# Vertical align middle for h3 tag not working

Tags: html, css

**Here is what I need the output to be.**

[image]

HTML Markup is:

```
<h3 class="TRM_Propane_sfty_ttl">Placement of Your Grill &amp; Propane Cylinders</h3>
<h3 class="TRM_Propane_sfty_ttl">Use of Your Grill</h3>
<h3 class="TRM_Propane_sfty_ttl">Other Propane Cylinder Safety Tips</h3>
```

What is the **CSS** I should apply to the h3 tag, so that the text "Use of Your Grill" will be vertically aligned at middle? I should n't use specific line height for the second h3 tag.

I tried display: table, table-cell, table-head. Nothing worked :(

Comment: I think a `ul` or `nav` element would make more sense here. the `h?` series of *headers* were designed as block level elements (e.g. to be their own standalone line.

Comment: You should change your HTML.  I cannot imagine a case where three consecutive H3 tags is semantically correct. I'm guessing you should probably be using a table and those H3s should be THs. And then you'll find that `vertical-align` works beautifully, too!

Comment: @DerekHenderson I wish this were an answer. Beautiful explanation. Its extremely unwise to use anything other than a table to represent data which visually shows a table. Hope I make sense. :-)

Comment: @DerekHenderson:
I have just cropped a single part of my design.
Actually there will be list of orders under every heading tag.
Going with Table, td is not a wise idea in a table-less code. rite?

Comment: Tables have a bad rap because people were using them for layouts for years. Tables are the best thing to use when you have tabular data. It sure sounds like you have tabular data!

Comment: @VelMuruganS, if what you are using is best represented in a table, then that is the correct markup to use, much better than using something else and styling it to look like a table. Tables should only be avoided if you're only using them for layout purposes; table is the correct markup to use for tabular data.

Comment: @VelMuruganS Table is designed for displaying data and why not use as what it is designed to do? And you could use th for your heading and td for your actual data to display.

Comment: @DerekHenderson, Edper: Agree you with both. I had a blender thought of Table is old. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to do it is to wrap everything in a new tag and apply `display:table` to it. The h3 elements should then be set to `display:table-cell`

Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/QSjM3/

Having said that, I do agree that three h3 tags in a row is unusual so you should consider re-structuring your markup

Comment: I find `display:table` scary.too much work involved. It doesn't stop there does it? You have to get `display:table-cell` right, the go on to apply `display:table-row` to its parent, then add `disp..oh wait, I feel so tired just typing this. :-)

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a drag all right. I rarely use it but very occasionally it's the easiest way to do something. It seems tables weren't all bad after all!

Comment: @cronoklee, tables were never all bad.  They were simply being abused, used for the wrong reasons.

Comment: @Derek Henderson I fully agree! In fact, I had just posted the same thing in the comments above!

Comment: I guess it's a question of layout vs representation

Answer (score 2):

`h3` is block level (that is the next element will go to the next line) so one way is to make that `inline` (like span element).

```
.TRM_Propane_sfty_ttl 
 {display:inline;}
```

in your CSS.

Check my [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cS4LP/5/) with `table` also by the way is used.

And without using `h3` element you could also make your font look bigger like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/cS4LP/6/)
and your code a little tidier ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use font-style on a span:

```
<span style="font-size:large;bold,etc.">
```

Make the span look like an h3, etc. It might not look 100% unless
you have made modifications to the h3 already (thus changing the standard h3 css configuration)